# Problem about one of my function in QtCreator that use qvector

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I need an help with one of the slot of my class. The implementation of the slot is this one:

```
void StudentsWidget::showStudents(ScuolaMaghi::Registro InsiemeStudenti) {
    while (!lookup.isEmpty()) {
        WidgetLookup info = lookup.takeLast();
        delete info.getWidget();
    }

    if (InsiemeStudenti.getTotale() > 0) {
        students_total->setText(QString::number(InsiemeStudenti.getTotale()) + "...studenti pronti alla battaglia ");
    } else {
        students_total->setText("nessuno studente pronto...ne conosci qualcuno?");
    }
    visualizzazione->render(grid, InsiemeStudenti, &lookup);
    for (QVector<WidgetLookup>::const_iterator it = lookup.begin(); it != lookup.end(); it++) {
        if (it->getEditButton()) {
            connect(it->getEditButton(), &QPushButton::clicked,
                    std::bind(&StudentsWidget::editStudent, this, it->getStudent()));
        }
        if (it->getDeleteButton()) {
            connect(it->getDeleteButton(), &QPushButton::clicked,
                    std::bind(&StudentsWidget::deleteStudent, this, it->getStudent()));
        }
    }
}
```

My main problem is that when I call this slot during a debugging session, the debugger stops on the first implementation line of the function, telling me that this has produced a call to one of the methods of the standard `Qvector.h` file which is `isEmpty()` and right on the line of code of this method the debugger stops me. What can I do to solve it? I tried pulling out that line of code and its block of statements but doing so causes the debugger to stop a little further on the second line of code that uses the `setText()` function for no reason.
Thank you in advance.

I tried to comment out everything that caused the debugger to stop but despite this the program stops on lines of code that I think are without problems anyway.

I'm using the qtcreator default compiler and in this situation the lookup variable on which the isEmpty() function is used is empty because I still have to fill it (I fill it for the first time a few lines later). I also don't have the ability to see if isEmpty() fails elsewhere, because I only use it in this slot and nowhere else.

these are all the functions that bring me up to showStudents: 1°) I created in MainWindow.cpp a new StudentsWidget with this code:

```
StudentsWidget *students_widget = new StudentsWidget;
stacked_widget->addWidget(students_widget);
```

2°)then i used the function:

```
void MainWindow::openDataset() { QString path = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,"Apertura DataSet","./","JSON files *.json");
 if (path.isEmpty()) {return;}
 if (repository != nullptr) {delete repository;} Students::Converter::Json::Reader reader; Students::Converter::Json::Json converter(reader); Students::DataMapper::JsonFile data_mapper(path.toStdString(), converter); repository = new Students::Repository::JsonRepository(data_mapper); reloadData(); crea_studente->setEnabled(true); 
}
```

3°)...and i called:

```
MainWindow& MainWindow::reloadData() {
memory.clear();
std::vector<Students::abstractStudente*> studenti(repository->readAll());
for ( std::vector<Students::abstractStudente*>::const_iterator it = studenti.begin(); it != studenti.end(); it++ )
{ memory.add(*it); }
students_widget->showStudents(memory.collector());
return *this; 
}
```

Comment: What debugger, how you run it, how is it configured? Is the problem only with this particular piece of code with all the names that you didn't explain, or any kind of slot that starts with `QString::isEmpty` produces this behavior?

Comment: Normally when a debugger stops you are supposed to look at the variables and determine why it stopped in this code. I expect `lookup` is somehow invalid or maybe the `this` pointer is invalid for the `StudentsWidget` because it has been accessed after the widget  has been deleted.

Comment: I'm using the qtcreator default compiler and in this situation the lookup variable on which the isEmpty() function is used is empty because I still have to fill it (I fill it for the first time a few lines later). I also don't have the ability to see if isEmpty() fails elsewhere, because I only use it in this slot and nowhere else.

Comment: Side note: I'd advise to not using the Qt container classes (unless you *have* to due to some Qt API). They made sense back in the day, but these days the standard library provides more efficient and better debugged (and more commonly known) implementations. So prefer plain `std::vector` over `QVector`.

Comment: i add a "!" before "lookup.isEmpty" I forgot to put that in the question

Comment: if you need i can pass you all the classes that are called

Comment: @JesperJuhl what can i use instead of isEmpty() and takeLast() with std::vector?

Comment: @drescherjm lookup is an attribute of the class and it is not initialized by me in the class but it defaults empty i think

Comment: @DaD8 for `std::vector` that would be `.size()` and `.empty()` and `.back()` / `.pop_back()`. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector

Comment: @JesperJuhl i tried with std::vector but debbugger still stops there in the condition of the while and shows me that:
bool empty() const _NOEXCEPT
        {return this->__begin_ == this->__end_;} 
with the script at the right  this:0x40

Comment: At this point I think that the problem is the inizialization of lookup, but i don't know how to do it properly

Comment: `StudentsWidget *students_widget = new StudentsWidget;`this creates a local variable and does not set your (member?) variable `students_widget `.
Please provide a minimal, compilable example to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @JesperJuhl When working with Qt application, I would not advice avoiding Qt containers. Mixing them with std containers will create messy code for little to no gain.

Comment: @chehrlic the variable studnets_widget works because when I start the application I have the material possibility to see the created widget, but the real problem for me is the function showStudents() that create an error on qvector or generally on vector, and I think this is probably because of the vecto widgetlookup but I don't understand why